# Docker checkpoint fails with SQL Server container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-checkpoint

After starting a Microsoft SQL Server (on Linux) container from scratch...

```
$ docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Pa$$word' -p 1433:1433 \
            -d --name mssql microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

... creating a Docker [checkpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint) ...

```
$ docker checkpoint create mssql cp1
```

... fails:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container mssql: 
failed to read checkpoint reader: 
open /var/lib/docker/containers/f2eb8d17e95630332bbeab887b9e03a1b91efcd8907f69b82805a788331316e2/checkpoints/cp1/cgroup.img: 
no such file or directory
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04, with [CRIU](https://criu.org) installed and experimental mode enabled:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:35:57 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       481bc77
  Built:            Sat May  4 01:59:36 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Checkpointing other containers works fine, only running into this with the SQL image.

Am I missing anything, or is this likely just a bug with `docker checkpoint` (which is currently an experimental feature)?

Comment: Docker is also installed on the ubuntu 18 machine or is it some other server?

Comment: Everything's on the same server

Comment: Try `docker pause <container>` and checkpoint after that and see if it works

Comment: try to run with custom named container `--name MyMssql` then `docker checkpoint create MyMssql cp1`

Comment: @TarunLalwani no luck with that: `Cannot checkpoint container mssql: cannot pause a paused container: unknown`

Comment: @MustafaSalihAslım the container was already named (`mssql`), the `docker checkpoint` command uses the container name. I forgot to include the `--name` parameter in my question though. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue using `docker` `19.03.1`.

Comment: @masseyb indeed! Confirmed repro with `18.09.6`, no repro with `19.03.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Docker `19.03.1`, this no longer appears to be a problem.